# Can this be refactored into a single database call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I have a listing of events in an `Events` model. What I need to do is visually group events by city/state.

Visually, that will look like this:

[image: Tracking details]

Here's, a stripped down look of what I'm doing in my view to make this happen:

```
<% @number.events.locations.each do |location| %>
  <li>
    <h4><%= "#{location.city}, #{location.state}" %></h4>
    <ol>
    <% @number.events.city_state(location).each do |event| %>
      <li><%= event.status %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ol>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

And the corresponding scopes:

```
scope :locations, :group => 'city, state'
scope :city_state, lambda {|location| {:conditions => ["city = ? AND state = ?", location.city, location.state] }}
```

The problem, though, is that I'm doing an additional database call for every location.

So can I get that down to a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eager loading to pre-fetch associations from your database:

If you're pulling all of your events at once, you could change it to pre-load the location associations for the events:

```
Event.all      # only loads Event objects from the database

#maybe try...

Event.includes(:locations)    # loads Event objects and their Locations
```

If you need events for some other object (like your `@number` object), you might want to do something like this in your controller, for example:

```
@number = Number.where(:id => whatever).includes(:events => :locations)
```

Now, in this example, your `@number` object will be pulled from the database along with all of it's events and all of those events' locations.

See the Rails guides for a little more info on this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

**Updated with my answer from the comments**:

Instead of using scopes, at all, you can simply use Ruby to do the work for you and cut ActiveRecord and extra database calls out of the loop.

`Enumerable#group_by` will take a collection and group by some attribute you provide.  In this case, you could take all of your Events, group by the city and state, and then iterate over the hash it returns:

```
events = Event.all
events.group_by { |e| "#{e.city}, #{e.state}" }
# => {"Birmingham, AL" => [<event>, <event>, <event>], "Nashville, TN" => [<event>, <event>]}
```

Doing this may be a little less pretty than using scopes, but it allows you to make one database call and leave it at that.

Comment: For clarification, `locations` isn't an association...it's a scope (see the list of scopes in my original post). I'm assuming that changes your answer, right?

Comment: Sorry, rushed through a little quickly.  Could you try doing something with the collection of events like `events.group_by { |e| "#{e.city}, #{e.state}" }`?  It's a little kludgy, but would certainly save you the database calls.

Comment: Where are you saying use that in my example? Because I'm already doing the group_by via the `locations` scope.

Comment: I'm thinking rather than using scopes at all, essentially you _just_ grab all of the events, then use Ruby's `Enumerable#group_by` to group them into "sub-arrays" based on their city and state.  It cuts the database out of the loop entirely, as you'll just be pulling all of your events once and working with them directly.  Using group_by as I outlined would give you a hash of the form `{"Birmingham, AL" => [<event>, <event>, <event>], "Nashville, TN" => [<event>, <event>]}`, which you could then iterate over and display however you choose.

Comment: Baron, the group_by ultimately did the trick perfectly. If you want to edit your original answer and I'll be glad to change my vote (it won't let me vote unless your answer is edited).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an O(n^2) solution, assuming your `locations.each do |location|` loop works as advertised. Should cut it down to 2 db hits.

```
<% @number.events.locations.each do |location| %>
  <li>
    <h4><%= "#{location.city}, #{location.state}" -%></h4>
    <ol>
      <% @number.events.each do |event| %>
        <% if event.city == location.city and event.state == location.state %>
        <li><%= event.status -%></li>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ol>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Not tested yet, will check back later.

Comment: Hmmm, how is does this reduce db calls? You're still running `@number.events` for every location, right?

Comment: Gotta check to be sure (haven't had time yet), but the first time you run `each` on @number.events it should hit the db and be cached, unlike the `city_state(location)` method call which is different each time.